# ruby on rails recieving error: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have an error in our erb files and the screen shot is here[image]

We have everything in games.html.erb as below

```
<h1>Games#game</h1>
<%= form_for(@game) do |f| %>
  <div class="game-field">
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
 <div class="actions">
  <%= submit_tag "Game Created", :class=> "btn" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

and here is the controller

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController


before_filter :store_location, :only => [:index, :show]
  before_filter :require_user, :only => :show
  before_filter :assign_game, :only => [:show, :destroy]

  def index
    @game = Game.new
  end

  def new
    @game = Game.new
  end

    @game.add_player_from_user(current_user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
       format.json do render :json => {
         :shouldStartNewRound => @game.is_ready_for_new_round?,
         :shouldPassCards => @game.is_ready_to_pass?,
         :isStartingFirstRound => @game.rounds.empty?,
         :shouldReloadWaitAutoPlay => @game.should_reload?(current_player),
         :shouldReloadAndJustWait => @game.should_reload_and_wait?(current_player)
        }
     end
    end
  end

  def create
    @game = Game.new(params[:game])
    api_key = ""
    api_secret = ""
    @openTok = OpenTok::OpenTokSDK.new api_key, api_secret
    session = @openTok.create_session request.remote_addr
    @game.update_attributes(:session_id => session.session_id)
    name = game[:name] # input from html
    @game[:name] = name # setting input into db object (model)

    if @game.save
      redirect_to @game, alert: "game created"
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def destory
    @game.destory
    redirect_to games_url
  end

  def reload
    reload_partial
  end
end
```

We are trying to create a deuces card game and we have bee stuck on that single problem. I have also looked for other similar problem that people have asked and we were not able to find the issue, it says that we have to put .new function to initialize the data. But the error is still showing up. Please help us!

Comment: please check the action new, there is something strange about it, probably you did not copy it right... Either that, or you are missing `def update`

Comment: could you be more specific, I am very new to ruby

Comment: please include the callbacks, they may be relevant. Also please specify what action triggered the exception. index?

Comment: take a look at the action `new`. After you assign `@game` you end the method and then add some more code without defining a new method.

Comment: ok so i think I know what you mean, I am having a constructor that calls itself, will it solve by calling create?

Comment: that did not work. I thought .new just initialize the data and it won't be nil

Comment: to what method does this belong: @game.add_player_from_user(current_user) ? What "def ***" preceeds it?

Comment: I thought we need to create form(a format), but seems like we don't need that for the #game.add_player_from_user(current_user)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `#game` method in your `GameController` class.

Rename your `#index` action into `#game` or your View file.

I don't know how your `routes` file looks like but I suppose that the `index` action is the action that you call if somebody calls the `root` route, so `http://localhost:3000/`. If that's right then you have to rename `game.html.erb` into `index.html.erb`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling the action #game on controller Games. There is no #game method defined on the controller, so the instance variable @game never gets defined like it does in #index or #new. You can create a #game method in the controller and define @game in that method as needed.

Also, you have some code in the controller that needs to be inside of a method, starting at `@game.add_player_from_user(current_user)`. Right now it's just executing at load time and probably not doing anything that makes any sense.

Finally, I noticed that you misspelled 'destroy' in a couple of places - search for 'destory' and replace with 'destroy' to avoid problems later.

Comment: what should the #game method do?